# Why do I get Segmentation Fault (core dumped) and no errors and warnings?

Tags: c

I wrote this code and after debugging for all the errors and warnings it seemed to compile, but it shows "Segmentation Fault (core dumped)" and I have no idea why it does that.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    int nrig, ncol;
    unsigned int **mat;
} matrice, *pmatrice;


void mat_alloca (pmatrice m)
{
    m->mat = malloc(m->nrig * sizeof(*m->mat));
    if (m->mat == NULL) {
        perror(__func__);
        exit(1);
    }
    m->mat[0] = calloc(m->nrig * m->ncol, sizeof(**m->mat));
    if (m->mat[0] == NULL) {
        perror(__func__);
        exit(1);
    }
}

void mat_stampa (pmatrice mat, FILE* f)
{
int i, j;
fprintf(f, "%d %d\n", mat->ncol, mat->nrig);
for (i=0; i<mat->nrig; i++){
    for(j=0; j<mat->ncol; i++){
        fprintf(f, "%2d ", mat->mat[i][j]);
    }
    fprintf(f,"\n");
}
fprintf(f, "\n");
}
void mat_leggi (pmatrice mat, FILE *f)
{
int i, j;
if (fscanf(f, "%d %d", &mat->ncol, &mat->nrig)!=2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s:intestazione file non corretta!\n", __func__);
    exit(1);
}
mat_alloca(mat);
for(i=0; i<mat->nrig;i++){
    for(j=0;j<mat->ncol;j++){
        fscanf(f, "%ud ", &mat->mat[i][j]);
    }
}
}
void mat_leggi_da_file(pmatrice mat, char *fn)
{
FILE *f = fopen(fn, "r");
if(!f){
    perror(fn);
    exit(1);
}
mat_leggi(mat,f);
}
void mat_stampa_su_file(pmatrice mat, char *fn)
{
FILE *f = fopen(fn, "w");
if(!f){
    perror(fn);
    exit(1);
}
mat_stampa(mat,f);
}
double media(pmatrice mat)
{
int i,j,somma=0;
int max=0,min=100;
for(i=0;i<mat->nrig;i++){
    for(j=0;j<mat->ncol;j++){
        int val = mat->mat[i][j];
        if(val>max){
            max=val;
        } else if(val<min){
            min=val;
        }
        somma += val;
    }
}
return (somma - max - min)/(double) (mat->nrig * mat->ncol -2);
}
int cmp(int *a1, int *a2, int l)
{
for(;l>0;l--,a1++,a2++){
    if(*a1>*a2) return -1;
    if(*a2>*a1) return 1;
    }
return 0;
}
void mat_bubblesort (pmatrice mat)
{
unsigned int **m = mat->mat;
int i,j,k;
for (j=mat->nrig-1;j>0; j=k) {
    k=-1;
    for(i=0;i<j;i++){
        if(cmp(m[i],m[i+1],mat->ncol)>0) {
            typeof(*m) tmp = m[i];
            m[i]=m[i+1];
            m[i+1]=tmp;
            k=i;
        }
    }
}
}






int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
matrice mat;
if (argc>1) {
    mat_leggi_da_file(&mat, argv[1]);
    } else {
    mat_leggi_da_file(&mat, "matrice.txt");
}
mat_stampa(&mat,stdout);
printf("\n il valore medio e' %f\n", media(&mat));
mat_bubblesort(&mat);
if (argc>2){
    mat_stampa_su_file(&mat, argv[2]);
} else {
    mat_stampa(&mat, stdout);
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: On which line does the program crash?

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the program with a debugger and finding out where exactly it crashes?

Comment: Error is only for syntax trouble. Warning are used to prevent some bugs. But, having no error neither warning doesn't guarantee you that you will not have runtime failure

Comment: Yes I have tried. And I have already debugged for all the errors, warnings and notes. Now the compiler only shows me the Segmentation Fault message. I don't know the line where ti crashes because the compiler does not show that and I could not find it on my own. @Bathsheba

Comment: @GiacomoMagai are you sure you have tried to use a debugger to step through the program ? because debugger will show you the line which produce the segmentation fault

Comment: *the compiler only shows me the Segmentation Fault message* is it, or is it rather your program which segfaults? Compiler does it's job when building the program, not when running it.

Comment: Yes I am sure. For the Errors it showed the line, but now for the Segmentation Fault it doesnt.

Comment: Your problem at the base is that you are trying to program a 2D matrix as a an array of pointers. Don't do that, C has native 2D matrices so just use them, something like `unsigned (*A)[n] = malloc(sizeof(unsigned[n][n]));` should do the trick with any decent modern C compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First issue, you are allocating 1 big buffer for the `mat` buffer, however, you are accessing it like a 2d array(row x col matrix). Fix the allocation try this:

```
void mat_alloca (pmatrice m)
{
    m->mat = malloc(m->nrig * sizeof(*m->mat));
    if (m->mat == NULL) {
        perror(__func__);
        exit(1);
    }
// problem here:    m->mat[0] = calloc(m->nrig * m->ncol, sizeof(**m->mat));    
    int r;
    for (r = 0; r < m->nrig; r++) {
        m->mat[r] = malloc(m->ncol * sizeof(int));
        if (m->mat[r] == NULL) {
            perror(__func__);
            exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Another issue is this typo in `mat_stampa` function, array index out of bound caused the segfault:

```
void mat_stampa (pmatrice mat, FILE* f)
{
    int i, j;
    fprintf(f, "%d %d\n", mat->ncol, mat->nrig);
    for (i=0; i<mat->nrig; i++){

        for(j=0; j<mat->ncol; i++){ // <=== here, should be j++ !!!

            fprintf(f, "%2d ", mat->mat[i][j]);
        }
        fprintf(f,"\n");
    }
    fprintf(f, "\n");
}
```

Comment: I have now tried this. Now the compiler prints on stdout 9 10 (which are the first two numbers of the file "matrix.txt", they are the dimension of the matrix) and the prints again Segmentation Fault core dumped.

Comment: @GiacomoMagai it is something to do with the file format, what's the order of the first two numbers? `rig col` or `col rig`?

Comment: This is the content of the file "matrice.txt"      `9 10
10 11 37 48 67 21 87 16 98 63
26 80 78 10 53 11 76 86 87 90
23 12 66 34 83 73 82 27 17  1
84 63 72 81  0 92 76 85 76 52
95 28 20  1 26 54 74 11 21 13
55 82 72 37 87 15 34 35  6 17
19 43 14 55 97 40 24 90 46 16
95 28 10  1 26 54 74 11 21 13
76 95 48 14 31  0 57 51 39 43` with 9 lines of 10 numbers

Comment: @GiacomoMagai another issue found, see my updated post.

Comment: This typo was the problem. Thank you for the big help.

Answer (score 1):

"Segmentation fault" means that you tried to access memory that you do not have access to.

There are four common mistakes that lead to segmentation faults: dereferencing NULL, dereferencing an uninitialized pointer, dereferencing a pointer that has been freed (or deleted, in C++) or that has gone out of scope (in the case of arrays declared in functions), and writing off the end of an array.

Comment: I understand those are the common mistakes, but I cannot find the point where I have made one of them.